# Saving Instance with Foreign Key in Django

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

```
class B(models.model):
    # some fields


class A(models.Model):
    b = models.ForeignKey(B)
```

Serializer:

```
class B_Serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = B
        fields = '__all__'


class A_Serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    b = BSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = A
        fields = '__all__'
```

Task:

```
def task():
    data = {}
    b = B.objects.get(id=1)
    data['b'] = b
    serializer = A_Serializer(data=data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
```

But the serailizer.is_valid() gives error that it expected a dictionary but got that object. 
Now if I do this -

```
data['b'] = b.__dict__
```

I get an error that B with this id is already present.
B is a modelSerializer and calling serializer.is_valid() from a function which is a task in celery

Comment: Can you please add full serializer  and view code?

Comment: For me it is currently unclear how exactly your view, etc. work, making it very hard to solve the problem. Can you post a MWE (minimal working example) that at least reproduces the error.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of providing `b` object to the serializer's data you can pass it to the save method, like this:

```
def task():
    data = {}
    b = B.objects.get(id=1)
    serializer = A_Serializer(data=data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save(b=b)
```

Note you need to make serializer's `b` field `read_only`:

```
class A_Serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    b = BSerializer(read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = A
        fields = '__all__'
```

You can find related part of the doc [here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#passing-additional-attributes-to-save).

Comment: But it never goes to the save method. It fails on is_valid() itself.
In order to pass it through is_valid I would have to make its as required=False in serializer.